# No module named 'six' when doing scons to build gem5

Tags: python, scons, gem5

```
~/Documents/gem5$ scons build/ARM/gem5.opt -j 4
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six':
  File "/Users/anuragkar/Documents/gem5/SConstruct", line 100:
    from m5.util import compareVersions, readCommand, readCommandWithReturn
  File "/Users/anuragkar/Documents/gem5/src/python/m5/util/__init__.py", line 46:
    from six import string_types
```

I have six installed on both python2.7 and python3 but this error keeps coming up. I tried doing 'import six' on both python2.7 and python3 shell and it works fine. Really clueless here.

Comment: Is your scons installed in a virtualenv? Is six installed there? which version of SCons? (please add this info to your initial question) Also which operating system are you on? (Looks like MacOS?). Also add the output from `scons --version` to your initial question above. (you can edit your question after you post it)